# ¿Cómo puedo descargar una imagen en un canvas como PNG pulsando un botón?

Tags: canvas

¿Qué código tengo que insertar en la funcion `descargar()` para que, nada más pulsar el botón descargar, el contenido en blanco y negro, es decir el canvas, se me descargue como un archivo png?

```js
function mostrar(){
  var archivo = document.getElementById("file").files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  if (file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(archivo );
    reader.onloadend = function () {
     document.getElementById("img").src = reader.result;  
     var canvas = document.getElementById('image');
     var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
     ctx.filter = "grayscale(100%)";
     var img = document.getElementById("img");
     ctx.drawImage(img,0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
     
    }
  }
}

function descargar() {

}
```

```html
<button onclick="descargar()">Descargar</button>
<input type="file" id="file" accept="image/*" onchange="mostrar()"/>
<img style="display:none;" id="img" />

<canvas id="image" width="400px" height="400px"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Pondré el contexto del canvas fuera de la función `mostrar` ya que no necesitas declararlo de nuevo cada vez que descargas una imagen.
2. No necesitas un elemento `<img>` para pintar el canvas, pero sí necesitas que la imagen esté cargada antes de pintarla en el canvas y aplicar el filtro. Para esto puedes utilizar `img.onload = function () {...`
3. En el HTML existe el atributo `download` que permite descargar una imagen. Por favor observa que el canvas está anidado en un elemento `<a>` Después de aplicar el filtro voy a establecer el attributo href de este elemento `<a>`: `a.setAttribute("href",canvas.toDataURL());` Además un mensaje que aparece en este momento indica al usuario que ya puede descargar la imagen haciendo click en el canvas. Un botón descargar antes de tener la imagen filtrada no tiene sentido.

```js
var a = document.getElementById("a");
var mensaje = document.getElementById("mensaje");
var canvas = document.getElementById("image");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function mostrar() {
  mensaje.innerHTML = "";
  var archivo = document.getElementById("file").files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  if (file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(archivo);
    reader.onloadend = function () {
      if (ctx) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = reader.result;

        img.onload = function () {
          canvas.width = img.width;
          canvas.height = img.height;
          ctx.filter = "grayscale(100%)";
          ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
          
          a.setAttribute("href",canvas.toDataURL());
          mensaje.innerHTML = "haz click en el canvas para descargar la imagen"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
canvas{background:#ccc}
```

```html
<!--<button onclick="descargar()">Descargar</button>-->
<input type="file" id="file" accept="image/*" onchange="mostrar()"/>
<p id="mensaje"></p>
<a href="" download id="a">
<canvas id="image" width="400px" height="400px"></canvas>
</a>
```

PD: puedes ver el ejemplo en codepen: https://codepen.io/enxaneta/pen/4cd829a2b035af24056387317d2eaf0a?editors=0010